# PowerShell -like vs -notlike (outputs are not correct)

Tags: powershell, foreach

Maybe someone can explain what is going on here. When I try to use -notlike vs -like the outputs are not catching the correct number of items in the FOREACH loop.  I would expect the outputs to just be inverse of each other not completely different.

When I use this code

```
$StudentADGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties MemberOf | Select Name,MemberOf | where{$_.MemberOf -like "*CN=Student*"}
$likecount = 0
$notlikecount = 0
ForEach ($user in $StudentADGroup) {
    $UserRoles = $user.memberof
    if ($UserRoles -like "*CN=ACTIVESTUDENT*")
    {
        $likecount += 1
    }
    else
    {
        $notlikecount += 1
    }
}
$likecount
$notlikecount
$notlikecount + $likecount
```

Ouput is

25786

220917

246703

When I use this code

```
$StudentADGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties MemberOf | Select Name,MemberOf | where{$_.MemberOf -like "*CN=Student*"}
$likecount = 0
$notlikecount = 0
ForEach ($user in $StudentADGroup) {
    $UserRoles = $user.memberof
    if ($UserRoles -notlike "*CN=ACTIVESTUDENT*")
    {
        $notlikecount += 1
    }
    else
    {
        $likecount += 1
    }
}
$likecount
$notlikecount
$notlikecount + $likecount
```

Output is

0

246703

246703

I would expect my output to be...
25786

220917

vs

220917

25786

Comment: if you're shifting the outer condition then shouldnt the inner conditions be inside the `else` instead of the outer `if` ?

Comment: Logic is not symmetrical. In the first example you only test the student name if they're already members of the `CN=ACTIVESTUDENT` group. In the second, your test the student name only if they're _not_ in that group.

Comment: I am pulling all groups that the user is a part of so they could be STUDENT, ACTIVESTUDENT, EMPLOYEE, EXEMPLOYEE, ALUMNI, etc.  Each user can have multiple AD groups they are in.  Here is an example output of roles for two different students.
```
$user.name
STUDENT1

$user.memberof
CN=STUDENT
CN=ALUMNI
CN=ACTIVESTUDENT

$user.name
STUDENT2

$user.memberof
CN=STUDENT
CN=ALUMNI
```
One of the students doesn't have ACTIVESTUDENT so if I were to use the -notlike ACTIVESTUDENT that student shouldn`t show up and if I were to use the -like ACTIVESTUDENT they should show up.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell's operators are working as designed, this is a simple logic bug in your code.

In the first example, you designate a user a "student" only if they:

- Are a member of the `CN=ACTIVESTUDENT` group, AND
- Their name starts with `n0`

In the second example, you designate a user a "student" only if they:

- Are NOT a member of the `CN=ACTIVESTUDENT` group, AND
- Their name starts with `n0`

These two sets of users obviously DO NOT overlap - the first criterion from each example is mutually exclusive with the other - you can't be a member of the group if you also have to NOT be a member of said group.

For a symmetrical example using `-notlike` you would need to swap the blocks too:

```
$studentcount = 0
$notstudentcount = 0
ForEach ($user in $StudentADGroup) {
    $UserRoles = $user.memberof
    if ($UserRoles -notlike "*CN=ACTIVESTUDENT*")
    {
        $notstudentcount += 1
    }
    else
    {
        if ($user.name -notlike "n0*")
        {
            $notstudentcount += 1
        }
        else
        {
            $studentcount += 1
        }
    }
}
$studentcount
$notstudentcount
```

---

In your updated example, you're getting differing breakdowns because of the way you're applying the `-like`/`-notlike` operators to a *collection of strings* rather than a single string value.

When used this way, PowerShell's comparison operators turn into *sieves* - they start filtering the input data:

```
PS ~> $UserRoles = @('ACTIVESTUDENT','ANOTHER_ACTIVESTUDENT','NOT_A_STUDENT','SOMETHINGELSE')
PS ~> $UserRoles -like '*ACTIVESTUDENT*'
ACTIVESTUDENT
ANOTHER_ACTIVESTUDENT
PS ~> $UserRoles -notlike '*ACTIVESTUDENT*'
NOT_A_STUDENT
SOMETHINGELSE
```

When placed in the context of an `if` condition, PowerShell has to convert the expression output to a boolean - and PowerShell happens to treat non-empty arrays as `$true` for conversion purposes.

So even though *some* of the students have `CN=ACTIVESTUDENT` appearing in *one of* the user role strings, all the *other* user role strings will satisfy `-notlike '*CN=ACTIVESTUDENT*'` because they don't contain that substring.

What you'll want in that case is `-not( ... -like ... )` - if the `-like` comparison didn't "find" the target group, the expression will evaluate to nothing, and PowerShell will treat `-not($null)` as `$true`:

```
$StudentADGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter "*" -Properties MemberOf | Select Name,MemberOf | where{$_.MemberOf -like "*CN=Student*"}
$likecount = 0
$notlikecount = 0
ForEach ($user in $StudentADGroup) {
    $UserRoles = $user.memberof
    if (-not($UserRoles -like "*CN=ACTIVESTUDENT*"))
    {
        $notlikecount += 1
    }
    else
    {
        $likecount += 1
    }
}
$likecount
$notlikecount
$notlikecount + $likecount
```

Comment: okay I took out the "*N0*" to show that even with switching things around the numbers are not coming back correctly.  The User.name is not all that important it is more about what AD Groups they are a member of.

Comment: That's because you're applying the operation to an array of strings ($UserRoles) instead of each string individually

Comment: so for the -notlike to work I would have to do it in nested foreach loop?

Comment: @SoullessViking I mean, it still wouldn't work, because all the other group names would return `$true` for `-notlike "*CN=ACTIVESTUDENTS*"` :)

Comment: Okay so then a -notcontains might be a better option than -notlike here

Comment: @SoullessViking Either that, or combine `-like` with `-not` - I've updated the answer to show how :)